# Hot-swap ServerSocket (Java)

Tags: java, sockets, hotswap

I am trying to write code to hot-swap sockets in Java.

Here is the gist of the code I am currently using:

```
// initial server initialization
ServerSocket server1 = new ServerSocket(port);

// ... code to accept and process requests

// new server initialization
ServerSocket server2 = new ServerSocket();

// attempt at hotswap
server1.close();
server2.bind(port);

// .. more code
```

The code works as above but I am wondering about the possibility of dropped messages between the time the first socket is closed and the second one is opened.

Two questions:

Is there a way to ensure that no connections are dropped?

If there is a way to ensure that no connections are dropped does it still work if the instances of the ServerSocket class are in different virtual machines?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Have you tried to repeatedly call `bind` on `server1`?

Comment: anders:  I am simply trying to accomplish code that will allow for another JVM to "take over" the server without losing any incoming requests or losing the current connections.

Comment: phineas: server1 is bound when it is constructed with the port number

Comment: @user1069760: Your "hot swap" code is within the same JVM ... You're not hot swapping anything. A 'ServerSocket' is simply a *listening* socket ... Your re-binding doesn't achieve anything useful.

Comment: greg:  Yes, I may have simplified it quite a bit in the code above.  The real code was much to long to show here but when the second JVM starts it signals the first to close the server then waits for the first server to signal it that the port is free and then it immediately binds to the port.

Answer (score 0):

The closing of a ServerSocket means that that `server1`'s handler does not handle new incoming connections, these are taken care of by the `server2`. So far so good. You can garbage collect server1 when it no longer has any connected `Socket`s left.

There will be a (shorter or longer) period of time where the port is marked as "not open" in the OS networking driver after the first ServerSocket is closed and the second one is opened (since the OS cannot know our intention to start a new socket directly after closing the first one).

An incoming TCP request during this time will get a message back from the OS that the port is not open, and will likely not retry, since it got a confirmation that the port was not open.

**A Possible work-around**

Use the java NIO constructs, which spawn a new thread per incoming request, see the ServerSocketChannel and be sure to check out the library http://netty.io/ which have several constructs for this.

Make sure that you can set the handler for the incoming request dynamically (and thread safe :), this will make it possible to seamlessly change the handling of the incoming requests, but you will *not* be able to exchange the ServerSocket (but that's likely not exactly what you want, either).